# Should We Centralise the components in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, components, code-maintainability

I have a question.
I am making a react-application for a major industry, which contains a huge number of components.
But I have found that most of my components utilised the same functionalities . For eg, I am making use of `Material Ui` as my UI Component Library.
I have around 10 - 15 `MUI-AutoComplete` components lying into different sections of the visible browser UI, and I have found that all of these autocomplete components share similar functionalities,
except for "options", onChange, onOpen, onClose, value, and RenderInput's which I could further remove using props, and switch-case logic.

I want to use my components as a single component say, `"AppAutoComplete.tsx"`, which takes care of all of my Autocomplete , that I am using into the different places throughpout my Application, only I have to import this file "AppAutoComplete" into where-ever I want to make use of them, and just tweaking and introducing a new case for each function I receive from the respective component.

I want to know, is this a good approach for centralising components for a major application?
Is this a good way of reducing the similar boilerplate code, from different places into the code base?
Would It create potential dangers, which I might not be aware of this way?

I think this way of writing code would help other developers to keep the track of code written for the app, and also aid in writing the maintainable code.
i mean, all you have to do is tweak/indroduce a new -case for your very new usage of Autocomplete.

the `switch` includes `props.placeName` as argument, which I would pass specifially for differnet places where I would Be going to use the Autocomplete

say , If I use autocomplete into different pages, then

```
**props.PlaceName**
case '`homePage`' : do something specific for home - page's autocomplete
case '`contactPage`' : do something specific for contact- page's autocomplete
case '`servicePage`' : do something specific for service- page's autocomplete, ...ans so on.
```

**Please suggest me what is the better approach?
Should I write the Autocomplete for every-single component, where I am going to make a use of it?
or , should I centralize all the Autocompletes, and target then with switch-case?**

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse creating a separate component for autocomplete is a good idea! you can create a AppAutocomplete.js file that takes properties such as "options, onChange, onOpen, onClose, value" as a prop and passes it into autocomplete component as a props and returns new Autocomplete component.

Comment: He is using MUI-Autocomplete so the component already receiving those props.

Comment: yes i know, but he can create a separate component that returns Mui's autocomplete component with dynamic props

Comment: I agree to the Hardik's answer, but I want to get myself prepared of the potential threats, or any - break-ins as it could break all the autocomplete into the entire application, since all the MUI-Autocompletes are now been centralized to just one "AppAutoComplete.tsx" component. I think centralising all the autocompletes would greatly reduce the duplicate code and also make app more compact. Correct me if I am wrong!